# Can't seem to make android state saving work

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm currently working on a little project to practice my Android developping skills. Right now I have 2 activities set up, the "MainActivity" and the "EnlargeImageActivity".

**EDIT: I'm working in kotlin**

The Main activity contains a bunch of textviews and an imageview to display information about a boxer. The boxers are all hardcoded in an array and I retrieve them by using an integer called "counter". The counter is set to 0 at the very start.

```
private var counter: Int = 0
```

Here's the catch, to move throught the list of boxers I've added 2 buttons: a "next" and a "previous" button. When clicked these buttons increase/decrease the counter by 1 and update the textviews/imageview.

Finally, when clicking an image I want to see it enlarged in a new activity. I made this work by getting the image from my boxers-array at the index of counter.

**The problem occurs when I move back from my EnlargedImageActivity to my MainActivity, the MainActivity completely resets to counter = 0, so the first element of my array is displayed instead of the element corresponding to the image I just enlarged.**

Here's the code for all that:
MainActivity:

```
    private lateinit var boxers: Array<Boxer>
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    private lateinit var nameView: TextView
    private lateinit var boxerIdView: TextView
    private lateinit var birthDayView: TextView
    private lateinit var weightClassView: TextView
    private lateinit var winsView: TextView
    private lateinit var lossesView: TextView
    private lateinit var drawsView: TextView
    private var counter: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            initialiseViews()
            addEventHandlers()
        }

        private fun initialiseViews() {
            imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
            nameView = findViewById(R.id.name)
            boxerIdView = findViewById(R.id.boxerId)
            birthDayView = findViewById(R.id.birthday)
            weightClassView = findViewById(R.id.weightClass)
            winsView = findViewById(R.id.wins)
            lossesView = findViewById(R.id.losses)
            drawsView = findViewById(R.id.draws)

            boxers = getBoxers()
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boxers[counter].image))
            val fullName = boxers[counter].first_name + " " + boxers[counter].last_name
            nameView.setText(fullName)
            boxerIdView.setText(String.format("ID #%04d", boxers[counter].id))
            val birthday = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(boxers[counter].birth_day.time)
            birthDayView.setText(birthday)
            weightClassView.setText(boxers[counter].weightclass)
            winsView.setText(boxers[counter].wins.toString())
            lossesView.setText(boxers[counter].losses.toString())
            drawsView.setText(boxers[counter].draws.toString())
        }

        private fun addEventHandlers() {
            val buttonNext: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonNext)
            buttonNext.setOnClickListener {
                if (counter >= 14) {
                    counter = 0
                } else {
                    counter += 1
                }
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boxers[counter].image))
                val fullName = boxers[counter].first_name + " " + boxers[counter].last_name
                nameView.text = fullName
                boxerIdView.setText(String.format("ID #%04d", boxers[counter].id))
                val birthday = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(boxers[counter].birth_day.time)
                birthDayView.setText(birthday)
                weightClassView.setText(boxers[counter].weightclass)
                winsView.setText(boxers[counter].wins.toString())
                lossesView.setText(boxers[counter].losses.toString())
                drawsView.setText(boxers[counter].draws.toString())
            }

            val buttonPrev: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonPrev)
            buttonPrev.setOnClickListener {
                if (counter <= 0) {
                    counter = boxers.lastIndex
                } else {
                    counter -= 1
                }
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(boxers[counter].image))
                val fullName = boxers[counter].first_name + " " + boxers[counter].last_name
                nameView.text = fullName
                boxerIdView.setText(String.format("ID #%04d", boxers[counter].id))
                val birthday = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(boxers[counter].birth_day.time)
                birthDayView.setText(birthday)
                weightClassView.setText(boxers[counter].weightclass)
                winsView.setText(boxers[counter].wins.toString())
                lossesView.setText(boxers[counter].losses.toString())
                drawsView.setText(boxers[counter].draws.toString())
            }
        }

        fun enlargeImage(view: View) {
            val imageToEnlarge = boxers[counter].image
            val intent = Intent(this, EnlargeImageActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(EXTRA_ENLIMAGE, imageToEnlarge)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

EnlargedImageActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enlarge_image)

    val image = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ENLIMAGE, 0)

    val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.enlargedImage).apply {
        setImageDrawable(getDrawable(image))
    }
}
```

**I tried to make it work by overriding the onStop(), onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance() -functions to save my counter using a constant but I can't get it to work properly. I keep just ending up the first element of my array.**

Comment: Try to use onPause() and onResume() activity functions for you purpose

Comment: You can try also another approach and use ViewModel

Comment: @ArtemBotnev hmm both of those options you said have nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce, do you have a clue where the issue might be here? I tried the onPause() and onResume() ones but, again couldn't get it to work. As for the ViewModel, I don't want to try that. I want to learn how I can do it the way I'm doing to get a better understanding of how things work...

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work unfortunately, but if you can put the project on github then I'll look at it.